# media folder suddenly empty

Tags: permissions, wordpress-theming, media

I'm trying to upload some images in my wordpress backend, but it fails every time. It could be permission issues because I have had trouble with that earlier in the project. But the weirdest thing is that I see on my server that the media folder is suddenly empty, while all the media in the wordpress backend is still there and the website is running fine. Anybody got an idea how this could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit one of the picture in the media on admin dashboard, there will be a text field titled 'File URL' on the right side.

Paste that into address bar and see if the browser loads it correctly. If yes then the problem is on the folder permission (or you might have opened the wrong directory), if not, you might wanna try to clear the browser cache or use another platform to open it.

Hope it helps!